# Add '%' sign to MySQL results

Tags: mysql, count

I am using a query to calculate total percentage but I want a '%' symbol to appear next to it. Any ideas that could help me

My query so far is

```
SELECT
student.StudentID,
student.`Name`,
ROUND (Count(attendance.AttendanceID)*100 / 6  ) AS Total,
student.WorkshopID
FROM
    student 
LEFT JOIN attendance ON student.StudentID = attendance.StudentID
GROUP BY
    student.StudentID,
    student.`Name`
```

Comment: Well it depends on where you want to show the data but in my opinion a query only needs to return the data, the formatting should be done in the application. for example if you show this in a SSRS report, add a format property to the textbox. Casting it as a string will break sorting for example unless you also add leading zeros. All that can be a bit messy

Comment: I am using this in PHP. I have nice little function which dynamically generates the table and I am using another plugin  called Datatables which adds pagination and sorting to the table. It's a prototype though so at the moment I just want to show that it can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CAST()` might not be needed, try with and without it.

```
SELECT student.StudentID
    ,student.NAME
    ,CONCAT (
        cast(ROUND(Count(attendance.AttendanceID) * 100 / 6) AS CHAR(20))
        ,'%'
        ) AS Total
    ,student.WorkshopID
FROM student
LEFT JOIN attendance ON student.StudentID = attendance.StudentID
GROUP BY student.StudentID
    ,student.Name``
```

The `ROUND` function returns integer data and `CAST` is needed to use the result as a string parameter of `CONCAT` function. `CHAR(20)` is really arbitrary - you can use any other string data type.

Comment: The `CAST` is unnecessary, at least in this situation.  `CONCAT` puts together strings; a numeric value (as from `ROUND`) will be automatically converted to a string.

Comment: This is why i told it might not be needed. I tried a similar query using MySQL Workbench and the displayed result was of type BLOB. I don't have much experience using MySQL so I went for a safer option.